# converting html in xml and xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

i am trying to code XSLT and xml..

one of the problem i am facing is i actually get the values of my xslt file from the xml file one of the fields like description have html tags

```
           <span class="text"><xsl:value-of select=BusinessDescription"  >
                </xsl:value-of></span><br />
```

so its outputting including the html tags like

```
                    <p> Hello there,</P>
                        <b>Hotel</b>
```

how do i transform the html on the web browser to show the output of the html tags??

like

Hello there,

**Hotel**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this question well, you are asking how to interprete escaped markup not as text but as markup.

**The answer is**:

This cannot be done in pure XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 (in XSLT 3.0 / XPath 3.0 there might be a function to parse a string as XML).

To do this you need to write an extension function, that takes a string, parses this as XML document and returns the resulting XML document.

**Therefore, instead of**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="BusinessDescription"/>
```

**the code that uses this extension function would look something like this**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="my:xml-parse(BusinessDescription)"/>
```

**The extension function itself** would be written in your favourite PL and will simply create an `XmlDocument` object and try to load the string (with a method such as `LoadXml()`), then return this `XmlDocument` as its result.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post the XSL and XML (try to reduce them to the smallest code that still produces the problem) we could give a more accurate answer. One likely possibility is that your XSL does not produce the `<html><body>...</body></html>` tags.

Your HTML content should enclosed inside the `<body>`...`</body>` element.